# Inline font/image alignment - font change for post content

Tags: css, fonts

First of all, let me say that I am not a professional coder - I've done every change on my site bit by bit and I'm not sure I really get how I made some things work.

That said, I had posted what seemed to me two simple questions (for people who actually know what they are doing on the Wordpress forums and received nothing but a smart@ss remark that I needed to learn CSS.  Anyway....

ONE  I have changed the overall fonts on the site but I can't seem to get the body of a post - and it alone to change to a better font for reading.  I have set up League Gothic as my main header, sidebar, homepage fonts but I need to change the font in the body of the post itself to something a little easier on the eyes.  And every combination I try changes ALL the fonts or doesn't work at all.  ANY good advice?

TWO  I have image/text just below the banner on my site.  There are two small icons on each side of the "navigation bar" I want all to be horizontally/vertically aligned but the two icons on each side appear just a little above the first line of text - and this shoves the bottom row of text onto the background image.

CAn anyone please tell me what I'm missing?

The site is thirdrailers.com

Thank you so very much...

(ALSO, There are other additions I will be making down the road - if anyone can refer a coder/designer I would be very grateful.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You want to change the font for: `#post-content p` and also `.recent-postwrap p, .main-postwrap p`. This will change the interior pages and the home page, respectively. You can add: `font-family: Arial` or whatever fonts you'd like to use.

2) Quick fix, though not the best. On the images, add style that says for the left image: `float: left; margin: 15px -20px 0 20px;` -- adjust those numbers accordingly. On the right image, just change it to `float: right; margin: 15px 20px 0 -20px;`.

Hope that works for you.

Comment: Matthew -  thank you.  working on that now...but cant seem to find the post-content p .... find the a, etc. but no p?

Comment: I didn't see it in your CSS earlier - so I'd just add it on a new line. `#post-content p{ font-family: Arial;}` etc.

Comment: Image tag should be like this: `<img alt="" src="http://thirders@thirdrailers.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/tr-iconleft.png" style="float: left; margin: 10px 20px 0 20px;">` ** Actual src might be different - but you need the `style=...`

Comment: Matthew... thanks for your help and your patience.  there is something I am just doing wrong and maybe I'm too "thick" to get it.  i made the change, but the right icon now disappears and the alignment on the rest is the same. :/

Comment: i also probably need to change the "at thirders" part too

Comment: You have a typo on your second icon in your code listing: `<img alt="" src="http://thirders@thirdrailers.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/tr-iconleft.png" style="float:" right;="" margin:="" 15px="" 20px="" 0="" -20px;="">` should be: `style="float: right; margin: 10px -20px 0 20px;"` In that line your quote marks got messed up.

Comment: I'm getting closer :)... the icon on left still is missing?  and which number do i tweak to bring the right icon further left..(towards the text) ?

Comment: On the left icon - double check the `src` part of the image tag. Make sure it's the right location of the icon. It should be somewhere in your media library in WP. To adjust the right icon, the `margin` tag works like a clock, starting at the top, then clockwise to right, bottom, and then left.

Comment: Mat -  got everything just right - THANK YOU...  

however, the left icon won't display?

Comment: left icon wise: your image is no longer pointing to where it was. If the right & left images are the same, use: `src="http://thirders@thirdrailers.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/tr-iconleft.png‌​"` inside the img tag.

Comment: I'm not sure what the actual location of the other image is. Go into WordPress and look under the media tab on the left. Find the image and you should be able to get the URL for it. Then, copy/paste that URL into the `src` spot.

Comment: Matt it's the exact same image as on the right.. same name/url, etc.  Is there something I need to change in the margins ?

Comment: MATT - got it, thank you so much for your help and patience!  

Question - do you do web design or ?

Comment: Glad I could help. I do more development than design work. Right now all I have time for is helping once/while on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Thank you so much! (do me one more favor?  just edit your replies to exclude the thirders@ part .... <site security reasons>

Have an amazing evening!

If they'd let me give you mad props I would.  BUT THANK YOU again for your help!

Comment: I can't edit the comments - too much time has past. Also - the code I shared is publicly available on your site in the source files. If you're concerned I'd consider adjusting how you call your images on the site and use WP functions to truncate the url displayed. See [this thread](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/images-within-wordpress-theme-files).

Comment: Thank you!  Now, to figure out the four other big other issues I have...  :)

Comment: Matt - can I ask you a follow up question when you have time.. since I seem to be getting demerits by posting it a separate question.

Comment: @KiranAidenO'Shay: Questions like this one, and the one you just posted are unlikely to be answered on Stack Overflow. Please read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). I'm not trying to be mean, just honest.

Comment: Matt... bit by bit I'm getting it.  Now just for the slider and I'm golden.  THank you again!